# Siddhi - Using javascript extension to query table

Tags: siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

is it possible use javascript extension on siddhi to query in-memory table or other database?

My function needs identify all elements in b-tree data structure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The script-js extension allows you to write simple JS functions to process streaming data. But it cannot directly access the in-memory table.

You can either do a select all on the table using Join, get the results, and then do additional processing using JS script, or you can process the incoming data using JS script or any other functions and then query the table appropriately to get the results (this will improve the table querying performance)